# App.xaml.cs methods call order in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have Windows Store C# app.

In App.xaml I have instance of Locator class:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary
        <local:Locator x:Key="Locator"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Locator class is initialized when app is starting when resources are loaded.

Now, I want to access Locator class instance from App.xaml.cs constructor.
But when app is starting, constructor is invoked **before** resources (locator) are loaded.

I would like to execute some logic from Locator class when it's available (when resources are loaded).

So far I have failed do to it with App.xaml.cs constructor, OnLaunched, OnWindowCreated, etc.
Did I miss any event or method in App class?
Any advices?

Comment: You should have access to the `Resources` collection during the `OnWindowCreated` override. Can you post the code you've tried? There is no way to access the object from within the App's constructor.

Comment: If those events are failing, please post how you are accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have access to the resources after Window.Current.Activate() is called in OnLaunched.  Anywhere beyond that point, your resources should be enumerated.